# For part a) am I on the right path? And how do I calculate the probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Let $N$ be the number of requests to a web server per day and let $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(λ)$. Each request $5$. Let each request come from a human with probability $p$ or from a spam bot with probability $1 − p$. Assume that the requests are independent of each other. Let $X$ be the number of requests from humans per day and $Y$ be the number of requests from spam bots per day
>
> (a) State the conditional distribution of $X$ given $N = n$, and state the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $N = n$.
>
> (b) Calculate the probability of getting exactly $x$ human requests and $y$ spam requests.

For a) I got $$P(x\mid N=n) = {n \choose x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$$

Am I on the right path?

c) Find the joint probability mass function of X and Y , and show that X and Y are independent
of each other.

im not sure how to get the joint pmf

Comment: The answer to (a) is nearly okay.  It should include random variable $X$ in the probability expression (we cannot have $x$ floating around on its own), and you should always indicate the support for the function. $$\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid N{=}n)=\dbinom n x p^x (1-p)^{n-x}~\mathbf 1_{x\in [0;n]\cap\Bbb N}~\mathbf 1_{n\in \Bbb N}$$

Comment: On (c): Take joint pmf from your answer to question (b).

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for Part A looks fine to me.

**Hint For Part B**

You are being asked to find $\mathbb{P}(X=x \land Y=y)$

Something else to point out is that $N = X+Y$

The probability can then be found as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(N=x+y)*\mathbb{P}(X=x \mid N=x+y)$$

Can you take it from here? (The $Y$'s don't need to be solved as they will have been determined already once you have solved it for $x$)